# SQLCMD mode and variables inside CREATE VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I am attempting to use sqlcmd mode vars inside my create view - is this not possible?

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[newTaxonomyMatterTypeId]'))
Drop view newTaxonomyMatterTypeId;
go
-- Create a view that has all of practice areas and all of Matters within the practice area using the new Taxonomy table
Create View NewTaxonomyMatterTypeId as (
select p.PracticeAreaId As NewPracticeAreaId, p.PracticeAreaEn, mt.MatterTypeId As NewMatterTypeId, mt.MatterTypeEn 
    from [$(Taxonomy_DB)].dbo.PracticeAreas p
    inner join [$(Taxonomy_DB)].dbo.MatterTypes mt on p.PracticeAreaId = mt.PracticeAreaID
    )
Go
```

Please advise.

thanks,
KS

Comment: why don't you use the actual db name instead of a variable?

Comment: A variable can be useful. For example, in production, you might want to move database B to a different server, and have views/procedures utilize it from database A on the original server. Meanwhile, in development, they're both on the same server. If you hard-code the database name into it for development, then it makes updating database A in production very hard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  You do not appear to be setting the Taxonomy_DB variable anyway.  First of all, ensure your SSMS is in SQLCMD mode (Query > SQLCMD Mode), then set your variable using `setvar`, either in the same script or a calling script, eg

```
:setvar Taxonomy_DB yourDbName
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[newTaxonomyMatterTypeId]'))
Drop view newTaxonomyMatterTypeId;
go
-- Create a view that has all of practice areas and all of Matters within the practice area using the new Taxonomy table
Create View NewTaxonomyMatterTypeId as (
select p.PracticeAreaId As NewPracticeAreaId, p.PracticeAreaEn, mt.MatterTypeId As NewMatterTypeId, mt.MatterTypeEn 
    from [$(Taxonomy_DB)].dbo.PracticeAreas p
    inner join [$(Taxonomy_DB)].dbo.MatterTypes mt on p.PracticeAreaId = mt.PracticeAreaID
    )
Go
```

Or:

```
:setvar Taxonomy_DB yourDbName
:r "c:\temp\yourview.sql"
```

You can also set sqlcmd variables when using `sqlcmd.exe` and the `-v` switch, or let Visual Studio Database projects handle this for you.